# How to add two data attribute check in cypress?

Tags: automated-testing, cypress

Example:

```
<div data-component="tab" data-value="first_tab">
</div>
```

How can I get `data-component="tab"` and `data-value="first_tab"` together in cypress command? Like I want to access select box inside `first_tab` and I want to be more context specific and write a more readable code: What I have tried is below (which is syntactically wrong)?

```
cy.get('[data-component="tab" data-value="first_tab"] [data-component="select_box"]
```

Comment: Same way you'd combine any two CSS selectors to refer one one element, concatenate them: `'[data-component="tab"][data-value="first_tab"]'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in CSS, attributes for the same element should be provided without space so,

`[data-component="tab" data-value="first_tab"]`  is incorrect

correct one is `[data-component="tab"][data-value="first_tab"]`

Now to find next element you can give **space** or **>** , space means any child and **>** means immediate child .

so the final locator is  `[data-component="tab"][data-value="first_tab"] [data-component="select_box"]`

And the command looks like :

```
cy.get('[data-component="tab"][data-value="first_tab"] [data-component="select_box"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate them as jonrsharpe said in the comment section:

```
cy.get('[data-component="tab"][data-value="first_tab"]')
```

if you then need to access another element inside this one, you can use [`.find()` command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find.html#Syntax):

```
cy.get('[data-component="tab"][data-value="first_tab"]')
  .find('[data-component="select_box"]')
```

then you can further chain some assertion:

```
cy.get('[data-component="tab"][data-value="first_tab"]')
  .find('[data-component="select_box"]')
  .should('be.visible')
```